# unable to run flask app using another port

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to flask. After installing it in ubuntu-lts, I tried to change the port but was unable to run the flask app from another port as another user is using an existing port.

I get this error :

```
from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 34455)
[INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Where is the mistake - installation or another problem? thank you.

Comment: pip install flask

Comment: @Nabin, your answer isnt helpful - I already wrote that I installed flask on ubuntu. My question was about the app failing and throwing errors when the port is changed. Do read my question before giving unhelpful answer and downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are on wrong dev environment.
Ensure you are on right python version and Flask is installed for that version. Now, what I mean by this is, that, a normal `pip install Flask` would install Flask for `python2.7`, but you seem to have tagged `python3` in the OP.

If you are intending to develop your Flask application on Python3, you might want to make a virtual environment using that will use Python3, then install flask inside that. Or else, you could tell Python to install Flask for python3 explicitly.

I agree that you might have installed Flask on your system, but I think the one you installed is for Python2 and you are trying to run the flask app in Python3 environment.

These are wild guesses as your question doesn't say exactly what environment setup you are on.

Comment: thanks @Sreenadh T C. although ubuntu uses 2x as default we are using python3 for devel stuff. I am not using a virtualenv. Before the import errors this was the traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker

Comment: solved the problem by installing Flask for python3 explicitly. thanks @Sreenadh T C

Comment: Awesome! Please close the question by voting the answer!